# Cannot transfer a file from one place to another using java codes

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using somehting like below :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(targerFile);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

    // get the response body as an array of bytes
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    // write for the destination file

    InputStream instream = null;
    if (entity != null) {
        instream = entity.getContent();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int x;
        do {
            x = instream.read();
            if (x != -1) {

                bytOut.write(x);
                instream.close();
                bytOut.close();
            }
        } while (x != -1);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        fout.write(bytOut.toByteArray());
        fout.close();
```

but only then i find out the inputstream from httpclient comes closed. so there is no way i can read it more than once. is there any work around for this? or is this not the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

use org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils:

```
byte[] data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

write that bytearray to a file with FileUtils from commons-io:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(destinationFile, data);
```

Comment: What's the point of reading into a byte array that might potentially become huge, when you could just write directly to the file?

Comment: if it still doesn't work, what's the output of
  `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
  response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();`

Comment: Christoffer, if streams make more sense in the given scenario, you could write to a ByteArrayOutputStream baos: `response.getEntity().writeTo(baos);`

Answer (score 2):

do not close the streams inside the loop.  do that outside the loop after the entire input stream is read.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you're closing your bytOut stream after 1 byte is read. But I would do something like this instead:

```
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) pw.println(line);
pw.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Do not use the default-encoding constructor of `InputStreamReader` unless you want to corrupt your data with a "randomly" chosen encoding depending on platform. Also, your code will not work with non-textual data, and it will potentially alter line endings and add one extra line ending at the very end if there wasn't one before. Since the OP wants to write to a file, there is no reason to convert bytes to characters with potential dataloss, so stick with streams.

Comment: I tried the print writer. but that is not helpin either. im still gettin the exception. is there something i am missing here. i am completly new to web services so right now i don even know if its my lack of knowledge or if it is a real issue.

Comment: Ok. all these i tried. buffered reader. printwriter. entityutils. nothing seems to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, your problem is that you're closing the input stream in the loop after the first byte is read. Don't do that.

Second, there is no point in writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` if all you're going to do is to just write it to a `FileOutputStream`. Write directly to the file instead.

Third, use a `byte[]` and `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`so you read more bytes at a time.

Fourth, disregard the above and just use [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).